# Angular: how set "priority" to HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

> Priority hints indicate the relative priority of resources to the
> browser. They can enable optimal loading and improve Core Web Vitals.

From https://web.dev/priority-hints/

example with fetch API:

```
<script>
  fetch('https://example.com/', {priority: 'low'})
  .then(data => {
    // Trigger a low priority fetch
  });
</script>
```

how set "priority" to Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)?

I have tried to force a priority setting:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <button (click)="makeRequest()">make request</button><br />
  <pre>{{ data | json }}</pre>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.makeRequest();
  }

  makeRequest() {
    this.data = null;
    this.httpClient
      .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
        priority: 'low',
      } as any)
      .subscribe((result) => (this.data = result));
  }
}
```

[online](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3u2zve?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

but doesn't works... priority is always hight

also suggested to angular team https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45426

Comment: follow this article https://medium.com/cloud-solutions-international/how-to-group-http-requests-into-a-queue-with-angular-interceptor-9aedd5560697

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below:

```
this.http.get<YourConfig>(this.yourConfigUrl, {priority: 'low'});
```

Comment: don't works... HttpClient don't have a priority options